# Jquery making input check box select all users from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This sample : http://jsfiddle.net/jahn08/f7debwj2/27/ it is working perfectly, adding names from table 2 to table 1.

what I want is when I click in the box select all too, right now I need choose **all** to select all names see this print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwtS6.jpg

**the target:**

```
  <div class="col-md-6">select all or none
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a id="checkAll">All</a></li>
        <li><a id="uncheckAll">None</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

if I click in the arrow and choose all, **this select all names**

if I click in the arrow and choose none, **this deselect all names**

**Problem:**

on table 2 in: `the select all or none`.

**1:** after click in the arrow : `<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and select all the

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
```

should be selected showing to the user all are selected, right now this not happen.

**2:**
if I click in the arrow: `<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and select none, this : `<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">`  should remove the selection showing to the user nothing is selected.

everything is working fine the only problem I have is on this

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
```

this box does not show if all users was selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/65/

Basically you will need to add an id for the checkbox and change the checked property

```
  $('#chk').prop('checked',check==1);
```

Comment: thank you, it almost what I looking for, I would like too if i click in the input type="checkbox" make select all, understand?

Comment: Yep. I understand. Checking to see how it can be done.

Comment: I believe this is what you require. Let me know if it is otherwise

Comment: yes and no :), but I want when I click in the <input id="chk" name="vehicle1" type="checkbox" value="Bike"> I will be able to select all understand? right now just choosing all from arrow, understand? sorry for this misunderstanding

Comment: You want to select based on the dropdown as well as the checkbox right? Sorry it was hard to understand but now i guess i got it.

Comment: yes coool very cool, 1 last thing, how can make it work in that sample? i change the json only: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/66/  , thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138030/discussion-between-iliketomoveitmoveit-and-raduken).

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically set value for "vehicle1" when you select an element from the drop-down.

```
    function checkAll(check)
        {      
            ....
                $("[name=vehicle1]").attr('checked', check == 1);
                return false;
        }
```

[Edited fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ava8r1no/1/)

Also, you should handle click on "vehicle1" as you do for elements from drop-down.

Comment: sorry i think i was not clear enough, what i want is when i click in the box select all too, right now i need choose all to select all names see: http://imgur.com/a/1gRwY

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML
======================================================
<p class="select_all"> All Select</p>
<p class="select_none">None</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="5">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="6">6<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="7">7<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="8">8<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="9">9<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="selection_chk" value="10">10<br>


jQuery
======================================================
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.select_all').click(function(){
        jQuery('.selection_chk').prop("checked",true);
    });
    jQuery('.select_none').click(function(){
        jQuery('.selection_chk').prop("checked",false);
    });
});
```